# Shopify text translation

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

My website is made by shopify and I use the dawn theme.
I've been trying for a few days to translate the word "Color" from inside the product pages into my language "Culoare". I looked for a solution on the internet, but I didn't find it. I don't want to translate the whole website because it is translated, I'm interested in translating only the variant picker metafield, the "Color" and "Size" options.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code inside your **main-product.liquid** so that you can use the **t** filter for translation:

```
{% if option.name == 'Colors' %}
    {% assign color_label = 'products.product.colors' %}
    <legend class="form__label">{{ color_label | t }}</legend>
{% else %}}
    <legend class="form__label">{{ option.name }}</legend>
{% endif %}
```

Then in your **ro-RO.json** add the reference to the translation:

```
"products": {
  "product": {
    "add_to_cart": "Adăugați în coș",
    "colors": "Culoare"
  }
}
```

It's the solution I came up with. Maybe there is a better solution.